# Naming inputs / outputs functions / events in a View Model

Tags: swift, mvvm, viewmodel

For example, there's a View Model called PokemonTableViewModel which is used to populate a TableView with Pokemon data from the backend. It uses RxSwift for the input and outputs. There's an input function (well, a PublishRelay) that will trigger getting the data, and three output events:

- Showing an activity indicator while getting the data
- Load the data when the data is retrieved
- Show an error message when the data retrieval failed

My questions are:

1. Which one is better to name the input?

   - Using the name of the action (eg. PokemonTableViewModel.getData)
   - Using the name of the View Controller's lifecycle method (eg.
     PokemonTableViewModel.onViewDidAppear)
2. Which one is better to name the outputs?

   - Using the name of the actions that should be done by the View (eg. PokemonTableViewModel.showActivityIndicator, PokemonTableViewModel.populateTable, PokemonTableViewModel.showErrorMessage)
   - Using the name of the actions that triggered the events (eg. PokemonTableViewModel.onDataLoading, PokemonTableViewModel.onDataRetrieved, PokemonTableViewModel.onDataFailed)

Thanks.

Comment: For inputs, I would go with the first option but I'd call it something like startLoadingData to give it an async feel. For outputs, I'd go with the second solution. Naming is important to prevent unwanted decoupling. The viewModel should not care what the view does with its outputs (like showing an activity indicator).

Comment: @RobC I am thinking the opposite, actually. VM must know about the View and should be coupled with each other in a way that a VM should only be paired with its own View and shouldn't be reusable with other views. Furthermore, by using the lifecycle method for input and the view's resulting action for output, it reveals intentions more clearly than just using the VM's supposed action for input and the resulting event as the output.

Comment: @RobC Eg. the intention of "when in viewDidLoad, I want to get data and show activity indicator at the beginning and hide when data is retrieved, but in tableview.reloadData, I don't want to show indicator" can be described more clearly with "onViewDidLoad" and "onTableReloadData" for inputs and "shouldShowIndicator(Bool)" and "loadTableData([Entity])" observable outputs than just "getData(showIndicator:)" input and "onDataRetrievalBegins(Bool)" and "onDataRetrieved([Entity])" observable outputs. But then again, it is a chore when you are refactoring from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`.